# EXCEL: Countifs statement that uses cell values as criteria

Tags: excel, variables, dynamic, formula

I have been banging my head against a wall for a few days with trying to make a COUNTIFS formula pick up four variables that may or may not be included in the criteria depending on what the user is wanting numbers on.

I have a front sheet where I want to show the number of unique events by a geographical area depending on the risks selected in the checkboxes in column F. There are some events that have more than one risk attributed to it so if only Risk-C was selected then all events with Risk-C flagged as Yes in the data set should be counted in the COUNTIFS in column B of the front sheet.

If an event has Risk-C and Risk-M flagged as "Yes" in the Data Set then they need to be counted even if only the Risk-C checkbox is ticked in the Front Sheet. This is what I'm struggling with at the minute.

Could someone please have a look at the attached screenshots and offer any pointers as to what I need to do to include the Checkboxes or True/False statements as part of the COUNTIF criteria? Or is there an alternative formula / function I need to look at? I use Excel 2016.

Many thanks in advance for anyone able to help me!

Andy

[Front Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqAGZ.png)
[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Sn0.png)

Comment: I often put values in cells to use as criteria, like so: countif(range,">"&C4)

Comment: So instead of having Yes or No flags in the risk fields I should convert to numerical values?

Comment: You can check for text: "Yes"="Yes" etc